# PHP file uploaden

Tags: php

I want to set a limit to the file that you can upload. Not how many but with file.

[image]

Comment: So you want to restrict file upload input by file type (i.e. extension)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hope this helps.

```
<form method="post" action="..." enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="image">Photo</label>
<input type="file" multiple accept='image/*|audio/*|video/*' >
</form>
```

you may remove the set you do not wish to upload

Comment: Yes this is what is needed. I don't no how to look for it. thanks